# Is it possible to use index and match while adding values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using this formula in my main worksheet in cell N3:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Totals!M$3:M$33,MATCH($B3,Totals!$K$3:$K$33,0)),0)
```

**Details:**

- `$B3` lists first/last names on main worksheet.
- `Totals!$K$3:$K$33` lists first/last names on "Totals" worksheet.
- `M$3:M$33` contains a numbers.

I'm looking for a way to count the numbers in column "M" if the names in column "K" match/are duplicates.

**Row 3**     "K" = David / M = 39

**Row 4**     "K" = Angela / M = 53

**Row 5**     "K" = Angela / M = 3

**Row 6**     "K" = Paul / M = 61

**Row 7**     "K" = Betty / M = 49

**Desired result:**
If `$B3 = Angela`, then "56" is the result found in cell `N3` on the main worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [SUMIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

```
=SUMIF(Totals!$K$3:K$33,$B3,Totals!$M$3:$M$33)
```